# Excel VBA Error 424 with lstDisplay.ColumnCount

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am getting a runtime error 424 in my VBA code while trying to display records. It does not seem to be acknowledging `lst.Display.ColumnCount` and `lst.Display.RowSource`. Would very much appreciate the help to mitigate the issue. Every time I run the code, it shows me the 424 runtime error message pointing to the `lstDisplay.ColumnCount` and `lstDisplay.RowSource` lines.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim AddNew As Range
    Set wks = Sheet1

    Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = TextBox1.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox2.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 2).Value = TextBox3.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 3).Value = TextBox4.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 4).Value = TextBox5.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 5).Value = TextBox6.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 6).Value = TextBox7.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 7).Value = TextBox8.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 8).Value = TextBox9.Text
    AddNew.Offset(0, 9).Value = TextBox10.Text

    lstDisplay.ColumnCount = 10
    lstDisplay.RowSource = "B1: J65356"**
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row - 1
        If lstDisplay.Selected(i) Then
            Rows(i + 1).Select
            Selection.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I expect a list to be displayed in my form but it keeps on showing the error.

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` on top, and is `lstDisplay` indeed a listbox?

Comment: Also, please note that B:J are 9, not 10, columns plus you are not actually assigning it a valid range from wks

Comment: Do you really have a space after `:` ?